# Dynamic return type from input function

Tags: c#, linq, function, generics, func

I like to implement a method with **TResult** depends on the return value of the input function **lampdacode** (just like System.Linq.Select) e.g:

```
public TResult Interact<TSource> (Func<TSource, TResult> lampdaCode)
```

The call should look like this:

```
bool isInit = providerService.Interact<Foobar>(x => x.FoobarInit());
```

with bool FoobarInit() as part of the Foobar class.

however the best i can do is to define the **TResult** as a generic:

```
public TResult Interact<TSource, TResult> (Func<TSource, TResult> lampdaCode)
```

Any ideas how to achieve this functional call without the need to pass the output type into the Interact call ?

EDIT:
ok i think i was not quite clear enough:

```
providerService.Interact<Foobar>(x => x.FoobarInit());
```

the providerservice holds a instance of type **Foobar** AND A LOT OF OTHER INSTANCES.
I like to give our developers the possibility to interact with the Foobar instance without getting the instance and than calling the FoobarInit().

e.g. in WCF scenarios this would be quite useful.

The developers should interact with the foobar instance via

```
providerService.Interact<Foobar>(x => x.FoobarInit());
```

however i like to give them a handy possibility to receive the returnvalues,
since this code gives me:

**Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'TResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: Do you really need to return something when you call x.FoobarInit() ? You can try Action<TSource> action.

Comment: What's exactly the problem? Type inference will take care of everything, there is no need to explicitly define `TResult` and `TSource` when calling `Interact`. And no btw, there is no way to avoid declaring both generic types.

Comment: FoobarInit() stands for a lot of function calls. 
I like to get the return type on compile time to prevent casting and errors of course. I like to have the same good behavior as Enumerable.Select.... a dynamic output type with depends on the returnValue of the lampda expression

Comment: And compiler inference will do so automatically for both `TSource` and `TResult` as long as you call with a fully specified lambda expression.

Comment: well, thats exactly what generics are for. Depending on what the lambda returns, the correct type will be inferred.

Comment: @InBetween Except in cases where the type of `x` can't be inferred due to e.g. overloading of `FoobarInit()`.

Comment: @NetMage I wouldn't call that overloading, its more the case of more than one reachable type declaring a method `FoobarInit`. You can easily solve that explicitly declaring the type of the argument in the lambda expression though.

Comment: @Servy since this question has an answer not applicable to your "Duplicate", I don't think it is a direct duplicate.

Comment: @InBetween Exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas how to achieve this functional call without the need to pass the output type into the Interact call?

No, `Interact` needs to declare the generic type `TResult`. The correct method signature is in fact:

```
public TResult Interact<TSource, TResult> (
    Func<TSource, TResult> lampdaCode)
```

> The call should look like this

No it shouldn't, ideally it should look like this:

```
var isInit = providerService.Interact(x => x.FoobarInit());
```

The c# compiler has a very good type inference algorithm, make use of it, there is no need to explicitly specify the generic types in your call.

Now, in your particular case, it's probable that you are running into an ambiguous call problem:

```
class Foo { public bool Frob() { ... } } 
class Blah { public int Frob() { ... } }

var res = providerService.Interact(x => x.Frob());
```

Ok, so what is `x` now? And `res`? You can easily get around this issue by explicitly declaring the type of the lambda's parameter:

```
var res = providerService.Interact((Blah x) => x.Frob());
```

Now the compiler will reason out all by itself that `TSource` is `Blah` and `TResult` is `int`.

Making a long story short, c# doesn't allow partial generic type inference but *you don't need it* in your scenario. You can achieve full inference of both `TSource` and `TResult` by simply declaring the type in the lambda expression.

Comment: the compiler is happy with that ... I'll test it! thanks !

Comment: and it works out! very very nice. And thanks for the good explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Interact` to be able to sniff the type from the signature, you will have to provide it in at least one place, somewhere.  Right now it has no idea that `x` is a Foobar so it can't infer anything about the call.

Maybe the simplest place is in the lambda's argument list, like in the following example.

```
class ProviderService
{
    public TResult Interact<TInput,TResult> (Func<TInput, TResult> lambdaCode)  where TInput : class, new()
    {
        var x = new TInput();
        Initialize(x); //or whatever
        return lambdaCode(x);
    }
}

public static void Test()
{
    var providerService = new ProviderService();
    var isInit = providerService.Interact((Foobar x) => x.FoobarInit());
}
```

No type arguments necessary.

[Check Example2 in my DotNetFiddle for proof](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xG7USa)

Comment: Except the `lambdaCode` is supposed to be generic in input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, C# does not support partial generic type inference. You can use an intermediate generic wrapper class to reduce instanatiation to one type at a time, but that isn't ideal.

Instead of calling like this:

```
bool isInit = providerService.Interact<Foobar>(x => x.FoobarInit());
```

You can explicitly specify the parameter of `lampdaCode` [sic] and have type inference handle the `TResult` type:

```
bool isInit = providerService.Interact((Foobar x) => x.FoobarInit());
```